# What are non-learning and learning VLANs?

Tags: switch, layer2, 802.1aq

I was going through some IEEE standards for switches (IEEE 802.1aq and IEEE 802.1Qca), and came upon a terminology of learning and non-learning VLANs.
I read that learning VLANs are used in Shortest Path Bridging VLAN (SPBV) and non-learning VLANs in Shortest Path Bridging MAC (SPBM).

I understand how MAC learning works (source address learning) and I also understand the concept of Filtering Identifier (FID) for Shared VLAN Learning. So I'm guessing learning VLANs (SPBV) are just normal learning switches. But what about non-learning VLANs?

Comment: Which specific document are you referring to?

Comment: @RonTrunk IEEE 802.1aq (SPB) and IEEE 802.1Qca (PCR)